# What is the way to insert a colon(:) after every two characters in a string?

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to figure out that -

**INPUT:** `String data = "506313B5EA3E";`

**OUTPUT:** `String data = "50:63:13:B5:EA:3E";`

I tried using-

```
java.util.Arrays.toString(data.split("(?<=\\G..)"))
```

But the output is: `[50, 6313B5EA3E]`

Comment: You could do it the old-fashioned way by looping over the string

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use a RegExp:

```
String input = "0123456789abcdef";
String output = input.replaceAll("..(?!$)", "$0:")
// output = "01:23:45:67:89:ab:cd:ef"
```

How does it work?

- `..` matches exactly two characters. `(?!$)` ensures that these two characters are not at the end of `input` (`?!` is a negative lookahead, `$` stands for the end).
- The matching two characters will now be replaced by themselves (`$0` means the whole matching string) and the colon we want.
- Since we are using `replaceALL`, this operation repeats for every two-character group. Remember: except the last one.

Comment: Can you add an explanation for your regex?

Answer (score 5):

Two simple options involving loops, both assuming you have already checked that the input is non-empty and has an even number of characters:

**Use StringBuilder**

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(data.length() * 3 / 2 - 1);
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i += 2) {
    if (i != 0) {
        builder.append(":");
    }
    builder.append(data.substring(i, i + 2));
}
String text = builder.toString();
```

**Use a char array**

```
char[] output = new char[data.length() * 3 / 2 - 1];
int outputIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i += 2) {
    if (i != 0) {
        output[outputIndex++] = ':';
    }
    output[outputIndex++] = data.charAt(i);
    output[outputIndex++] = data.charAt(i + 1);
}
String text = new String(output);
```

Another option would be to use [`Joiner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) along with your previous split:

```
String text = Joiner.on(':').join(data.split("(?<=\\G..)"));
```